# Got "Could not find resource 'src/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml" when using spring boot 1.3.1

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Should not maven-checkstyle-plugin provides default config xml file?
Why got this error when running maven?

I can't google some solution for this issue , please help me get it, Thanks!

The error message as below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check
>   (checkstyle-validation) on project explorer-parent: Failed during
>   checkstyle execution: Unable to find suppressions file at location:
>   src/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml: Could not find resource
>   'src/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml'. -> [Help 1]

---

> attached pom file:
>   [parent pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49dED.png)
>   [module pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXMBS.png)

Comment: Can you share your pom file please? It looks like you've picked up the configuration from Spring Boot's own build so I'd guess that you're using the wrong parent.

Comment: I encountered this problem, it shows that you add the spring-boot-starter-parent as parent of your maven project, but you didn't add spring-boot-starter as dependency.

Comment: Already attached my pom file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using the wrong parent in your `pom.xml file`. You are using `spring-boot-parent` but it should be `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Update the `pom.xml` of `explorer-parent` so that its `<parent>` looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```